# How can I get the intersection of rows within a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
User_id, Key, Value
```

In this table are records such as:

```
1, "first name", "Bob"  
2, "first name", "Mike"  
1, "last name", "Jones"  
2, "last name", "Carter"
```

I want to get the user_id for a specific first and last name pair. How can I get a query to do this? For example, I want to get 1 if I query for Bob Jones

Comment: Will you always have two input keys: one first name and one last name?

Comment: Yes, if theres a row with a first name key, then there will be a row with a last name key

Comment: I do not understand why you structure your data in this way. Why can't you just put all name in one row.

Comment: i think this is just a lab.

Comment: You should create a `Users` table with `id, first_name, last_name` fields. Key/value tables can be useful for non-relational stuff, like configuration, but if the data is relational then it should be in separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself:

```
SELECT t1.User_id
FROM myTable t1
JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.User_Id = t2.UserId
WHERE t1.Key = 'first name' AND t2.Key = 'last name'
AND t1.Value = "Bob" AND t2.Value = "Jones"
```

Or with following *concatenated* condition:

```
SELECT t1.User_id
FROM myTable t1
JOIN myTable t2 ON t1.User_Id = t2.UserId
WHERE t1.Key = 'first name' AND t2.Key = 'last name'
AND (t1.Value + ' ' + t2.Value) = "Bob Jones"
```

Comment: both your queries are not optimal. but second is extreamly bad. it will require o(n2) complexity(will simple check full join)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 tasks here
1) Got first and last name in different values

2) Got row which have same id and first =your_first+ last=your_last

Simple query will be:

```
 select user_id from tab1 
 where 
   key="first name" and value=your_first 
   and 
   user_id in (select  user_id from tab1 where key="last name" and value=your_last)
```

But i am afraid that will be bad optimized by mysql

Considering your user_id have index, best query will be

```
select a.user_id from (
 select user_id from tab1 where key="first name" and value=your_first )
)a left join 
 (select  user_id from tab1 where key="last name" and value=your_last) as b
 on a.user_id=b.user_id where b.user_id is not null;
```

If you can't got your_first/your_last name in upper level(php?) script, you can replace it with

```
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',1)

   SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,' ',2)
```